# Prev and next buttons for scroll in javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a section in the website where I need to show `facebook` feed. 
I have two buttons as you can see in the picture. With the buttons I need to 'scroll' between the news feed.
[image]

I should do this with javascript or jquery, but I'm very new to these programming languages.

```css
.content .tab-pane > #facebook_ticker > li{
 max-height: 165px;
 min-height:165px;
}
.content .second-row .tab-content  .ticker-controls,
.single .content  .tab-content  .ticker-controls{
 background:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 height: 35px;
 padding: 5px 20px;
 margin-top: -10px;
 font-family: 'TGLTCER';
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden-xs">
                <h1 id="tgb_head"><span id="facebook_icon" class="social-content-icon"></span> Facebook</h1>
                    
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active fade in">
         <ul class="list-unstyled" id="facebook_ticker">
             <?php echo do_shortcode("[custom-facebook-feed]"); ?> 
          </ul>
       </div>
     <div id="facebook_ticker_controls" class="ticker-controls">
    <a href="#" class="prev pull-left test" id="fprev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>&nbsp; Previous</a> 
    <a href="#" class="next pull-right test" id="fnext">Next &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a> 
   </div>
                      
 </div><!-- end tab-content -->
                    
 </div><!-- end facebook -->
            
            
 <!-- The  ?php echo do_shortcode("[custom-facebook-feed]"); ? generates the following code--> 
                
                
 <div class="cff-wrapper">
   <div id="cff" data-char="400" class="cff-width-resp cff-default-styles" style="padding:5%; ">
   
   <div class="cff-item cff-link-item author-princeton-partners-inc-" id="cff_92134012073_10155928811127074" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; "><div class="cff-author"><a href="https://facebook.com/92134012073" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="Princeton Partners, Inc. on Facebook"><div class="cff-author-text"><p class="cff-page-name cff-author-date">Princeton Partners, Inc.</p><p class="cff-date"> 3 days ago </p></div><div class="cff-author-img"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/92134012073/picture?type=square" title="Princeton Partners, Inc." alt="Princeton Partners, Inc." width="40" height="40"></div></a></div><p class="cff-post-text"><span class="cff-text" data-color="">At PPI, we love all things spooky. Check out our website to find our special Halloween video reel and a kit to throw your own Gargoyle-style X-Files party. Have a ghoulish day! </span><span class="cff-expand">... <a href="#" style="color: #"><span class="cff-more">See More</span><span class="cff-less">See Less</span></a></span></p><div class="cff-shared-link" style="border: 1px solid #; "><div class="cff-text-link cff-no-image"><p class="cff-link-title"><a href="" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" style="color:#;">Check out this link</a></p><p class="cff-link-caption" style="color:#;"><a class="vglnk" href="" rel="nofollow"><span>princetonpartners</span><span>.</span><span>com</span></a></p><p class="cff-post-desc" style="font-size:12px; "><span>  </span></p></div></div><div class="cff-post-links"><a class="cff-viewpost-facebook" href="" title="View on Facebook" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">View on Facebook</a><div class="cff-share-container"><span class="cff-dot">·</span><a class="cff-share-link" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Share">Share</a><p class="cff-share-tooltip"><a href="" target="_blank" class="cff-facebook-icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a><a href="" target="_blank" class="cff-twitter-icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a><a href="" target="_blank" class="cff-google-icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a><a href="" target="_blank" class="cff-linkedin-icon"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a><a href="" target="_blank" class="cff-email-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a><i class="fa fa-play fa-rotate-90"></i></p></div></div></div>
   
   
   </div>
```

I have tried something like this:

```
  <script>
  $('#facebook_ticker_controls a.prev').click(function() {
  $.scrollTo($(this).closest('cff-item').prev(),800);
  });

  $('#facebook_ticker_controls a.next').click(function() {
  $.scrollTo($(this).closest('cff-item').next(),800);
  }); 
  </script>
```

but it does nothing.Can you please give me a hint what to try in order to resolve this problem? Thanks

Comment: You might want to [look into this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

Comment: This is not a `facebook` question btw. This question does not depend at all on where the content comes from. If it was static content, it would still be exactly the same problem. So please use tags appropriately.